# Upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04, will apps have to be reinstalled

Tags: upgrade

If I upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 using the ubuntu update manager, will my applications remain the same? Or will I have to reinstall the applications again after upgrade? Also, will my unity app launcher remain unchanged? thank you

Answer (score 1):

update will not damage the files whatsoever, however apps lacking the 14.04 support might cause problems. It will ask you removal of ppa's in that case Everything personal should remain same after the process, however i would take a backup using "aptik" for apps and copy my personal files somewhere safe incase of things get dirty